# Responsive multi level menu not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using [this plugin](http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/index.html) in my app

Here it is [my app](http://1stfold.com/taskbox/dev/POS/angular/#/app/scan/)

You can see menu by clicking third green button then any yellow button on right side. Menu open but it is under the other div so it is not clickable. I have applied

```
position:absolute;
z-index:99999
```

But it does not come over the `div`.

any idea?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

add z-index on your "dl-menuwrapper" class:

```
.dl-menuwrapper {
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 200%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```